# Circle Detection inside Images

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, hough-transform, pattern-recognition

I've developed a circle detection algorithm to recognise empty circles or filled circles for marking multiple-choice questions using Hough Circle Transform in OpenCV. However, I've tried to adjust the parameters for the HoughCircles and it doesn't work. I found that the source images varies by contents (circles' size, noise content) and it sometimes even recognises noises as one of the circles. For those samples containing the out-of-bounds blackened circles also cannot be recognised well.

Therefore, I'm thinking of using deep learning or neural network stuff to train a recognition model, so that it can recognise the correct circles of the choices, as well as the positions.

Here're some examples of the results from current algorithm:

- [Normal detection - Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQhF1.png)
- [Normal detection - Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYAEz.png)
- [Out-of-bounds blackened circle - Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l4Wx.png)
- [Out-of-bounds blackened circle - Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p9JX.png)
- [Noise content detected - Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGC8P.png)
- [Noise content detected - Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4wAA.png)

Current recognition algorithm using OpenCV:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('source.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_blurred = cv2.blur(gray, (5, 5))

detected_circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray_blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 30, param1 = 200, param2 = 30, minRadius = 15, maxRadius = 40)

if detected_circles is not None:
    detected_circles = np.uint16(np.around(detected_circles))

    for pt in detected_circles[0, :]:
        a, b, r = pt[0], pt[1], pt[2]
        cv2.circle(img, (a, b), r, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        cv2.circle(img, (a, b), 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.imshow("Detected Circles", img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

How can the circles (including blackened and out-of-bound blackening circles) be recognised accurately? Thanks if someone could help!

Comment: For a problem like this, you will likely need to implement a deep learning approach to get the results that you're looking for.  How much data do you have? Is your data labeled?

Comment: Thanks for reply, @MaxFeinberg! Currently I have around 300 - 400 raw image data, but they aren't labeled.

Comment: Ah okay, that is not really enough data to develop a robust deep learning model (even starting from a pre-trained model).  Have you thought about trying to use patterns of the properly found circles to better inform the model? Ex: identify cases where the x/y coordinates are the same so you know when they are aligned horizontally or vertically to limit/hone the search.

Comment: For the dataset, it can be obtained more but how large would the size of dataset be suitable for developing the model? Regarding the method of coordinate alignment, I've thought before but it might not work because the source images are scanned and the scanning quality (it might be rotated by some degrees) would be varying.

Comment: Rotation is also something that can be dealt with in images.  You could get started with a deep learning model with samples in the low thousands.

Comment: If the print templates for the survey are the same, then it may be easier to find a match between them. Then you can find a clean template. And get the difference between a template with and without markers. Those. we get a picture only with handwritten marks.

Comment: Thanks @AlexAlex! However, the templates will vary since the application will be handling different types of papers containing different questioning styles. It is not possible to have a fixed pattern.

Comment: @MaxFeinberg Sorry that misunderstood your comment. Do you mean to develop a model as well as considering coordinate alignment to speed up the search?